# LAMPP website can't be viewed by other computers?

Tags: web, lampp

I have a VMware workstation which has Ubuntu in it and I've also installed LAMPP on it, I have already created a full running website using php. I could access the website on my local computer(where the vmware is installed) by using the ip address however if i try using other computers, I couldn't open the website. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that you probably have the VM interface card in NAT mode. If the interface is in NAT mode, your Ubuntu VM will be "hidden" behind the VM host.

Change the Virtual Machine network interface card to bridged mode, in Virtual Machine settings -> Network Adapter.

After setting the interface do Bridged mode, if you have a DHCP server on your network, you only have to renew the IP address of the Ubuntu machine (if it didn't do it automatically).

Check the new IP address of the Ubuntu machine (should be an IP address of your LAN). Use this IP to contact the web server.